# Is it possible to add days to the date in the template?

Tags: django

I have today's date in my template, which is in a loop. I want to add a counter to the cycle so that in the template I don't have today's date, but date + 1 day, date + 2 days, and so on.

```
  {% for day_week_list in set_day_week %}
        <div class="card mb-2">
          <div class="card-header">
            {{ day_week_list }} {{ day_data|date:'d.m' }}
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
```

Comment: You can achieve this with custom templatetags I believe. read more about custom templatetags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. To add days to a date in HTML, you need to use a programming language such as JavaScript.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).